# Optimizing dataframe manipulation: new column based on conditional logic and multiple columns

Tags: python, performance, pandas, optimization, dataframe

Currently, this works:

```
df['new'] = df.apply( \
       lambda x: address[int(x['c1'][:5], 2)]+'_'+str(int(x['c1'][6:11], 2)) \
       if x['c1'][5] == '1' \
       else address[int(x['c2'][:5], 2)]+'_'+str(int(x['c2'][6:11], 2)), axis=1) `
```

`address` is a dictionary.

But it's **really slow**. Specifically, `apply`ing to the whole dataframe is considerably slower than `apply`ing to a selected column. However, the new column is based on multiple columns and I'm not sure how to implement that.

Additionally, is there a way to vectorize these types of logical/conditional statements?

sample dataframe:

`<bound method DataFrame.head of                      c1                c2
0      0000100111000111  0010110011000111
1      0001000111000111  0010110011000111
2      0101010001001010  0000000000000000
3      0101010010001110  0000000000000000
4      0101010011101010  0000000000000000
5      0111111100000100  0000000000000000
6      0111110010010110  0000000000000000
7      1000000001001100  0000000000000000
8      1110011110001000  0000000000000000
9      0000100001010000  0000000000000000
10     0001000001001010  0000000000000000
11     0101101100100100  0000000000000000
12     1110001100100100  0000000000000000
13     0010100101101001  0101010101101001
14     0000100101100000  0000000000000000
15     0000100110100000  0000000000000000
16     0001000101101011  0000000000000000
17     1001110000100001  0000000000000000
18     0111111000100000  0000000000000000
19     1000000100010110  0000000000000000
20     1110001111000010  0000000000000000
21     1011010001000010  0000000000000000
22     0110010001001111  0000000000000000
23     0111110000110101  0000000000000000
24     0111110001001100  0000000000000000
25     1000000000111101  0000000000000000
26     0000110001100010  0000000000000000
27     0001010001100010  0000000000000000
28     1100100100100101  1001011000000101
29     0101000010101010  0111110001001010
...                 ...               ...
95714  0101111100011000  0000000000000000
95715  0010101011001011  0000000000000000
95716  0010100111100110  0101010110100110
95717  0010101000100100  0101011011100100
95718  0101000110000101  0000000000000000`

Comment: `df.apply` in combination with `lambda` is always very slow. Please show a sample of your dataframe.

Comment: You cannot ask one question, get an answer, and then say that you really meant to ask a different question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need vectorized `if-then-else` also known as `np.where` (`np` stands for `numpy`, just in case).

```
import numpy as np
df['new'] = np.where(df['c1'].str[5] == '1',
                     df['c1'].str[:5], 
                     df['c2'].str[:5])
#                 c1                c2    new
#0  0000100111000111  0010110011000111  00101
#1  0001000111000111  0010110011000111  00101
#2  0101010001001010  0000000000000000  01010
#....
```

Comment: thanks very much! i'll try this and PaSTE's answer to see which is faster

Comment: OK, I'm running into issues because I may have oversimplified what my code actually looks like. I've edited my original code

Comment: I do not see any recent edits. My answer matches your code. Did you copy the answer correctly? What are the "issues"?

Comment: just changed. there is now added complexity of `str()`, `int()`, dictionaries, and string concatenation

Comment: @MattTakao it is bad form to change the nature of the question.  It completely wastes the people's time who were trying to help you.  It also renders any answers prior to your edit irrelevant.  It would be so much better to accept the best answer and ask a new question.

Comment: Sorry about that. I found all the answers here very useful, I'll just do my best with what everyone gave me and avoid asking questions in the future, I don't seem to be any good at it haha

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you are trying to do an operation based on the character value of a string column `c1`.  Doing row-wise string manipulation like this is slow, but pandas can help you out with the [`.str` functions](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/text.html):

```
# begin by setting all of the values to what you want from c1
df['new'] = df['c1'].str.slice(stop=5)

# replace those that meet your criteria with what you want from 'c2'
df.loc[df['c1'].str.get(5) == '1', 'new'] = df['c2'].str.slice(stop=5)
```

Answer (score 2):

Using Boolean ~

```
df['New']=df.c1.str[:5]
df.loc[df.c1.str[5]=='1','New']=(df.c2.str[:5])[df.c1.astype(str).str[5]=='1']
```

Comment: @jezrael Enjoy your vacation ~~:-)